# When no write, why Elasticsearch performs indexing every 'n' seconds?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, opensearch

I have basic question regarding elastic search.

As per documentation : **By default, Elasticsearch periodically refreshes indices every second, but only on indices that have received one search request or more in the last 30 seconds.**
Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html#refresh-api-desc

Also as per documentation: **When a document is stored, it is indexed and fully searchable in near real-time--within 1 second.**
Reference : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/documents-indices.html

So when write happens, indexing happen. When write is not happening and documents are already indexed, then why elastic search indexes every 1 second existing documents?

Answer (score 1):

it's not indexing existing documents, that's already been done

it's checking to see if it needs to write any in memory indexing requests that need to be written to disk to make them searchable